# How to Filter Enum and Use it in Dropdown

Tags: c#, jquery, linq, enums

I am new to `MVC 5` and My goal is to filter the list in my `enum` that I will show in my dropdown list

```
public enum DayofWeekType
{
      Monday=1,
      Tuesday= 2,
      Wednesday=3,
      Thursday=4,
      Friday= 5,
      Saturday=6,
      Sunday= 7
}
```

And I just want to show is friday,saturday and sunday in dropdown when the logged user is Not Administrator, I cant find solution on filtering `enum` field in `Model`, tried adding Conditions in model but always sums up with errors. Tried searching for `LINQ` and `jQuery` solutions.

Comment: It's just enum definition. Where is your filtering code? What is wrong with your code? You have error? Values are not filtered? Currently it looks like you want us to solve your task from beginning to the end

Comment: How does your model look like?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy no sir, I just want to know if theres a workarround here

Comment: can you show your view code?

Answer (score 2):

you can do it like this

```
   var enumlist =  Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayofWeekType)).Cast<DayofWeekType>().Select(v => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = v.ToString(),
        Value = ((int)v).ToString()
    });

    if (IsUser) //your condition here
    {
      enumlist=  enumlist.Skip(4);

    }

    ViewBag.enumlist = enumlist;
```

and in your view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x=>x.Id,(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag.enumlist)
```

`.Skip` will skip first `4` values and start with `5th` value which is `Friday`

Answer (score 0):

```
var weekValues = System.Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayofWeekType));
var weekNames = System.Enum.GetNames(typeof(DayofWeekType));

for (int i = 0; i <= weekNames.Length - 1 ; i++) {
    ListItem item = new ListItem(weekNames[i], weekValues[i]);
    ddlList.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter it at controller level follow the below steps to achieve

```
            int[] eliminateDays = null;
            // wrap enum into collection
            var enumDaysCollection = (from dayName in Enum.GetNames(typeof(DayofWeekType))
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      Text = dayName.ToString(),
                                      Value = (int)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayofWeekType), dayName)
                                  }).ToList();
            // array contain days (enum values) which will be ignored as per user specific
            // lets say you want to ignore monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday 
            if (User.IsInRole("SomeUserRole"))
            {
                eliminateDays = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
            }
            else if (User.IsInRole("AnotherUserRole"))
            {
                eliminateDays = new int[] { 1, 3 };
            }
            else
            {
                //For Admin will make empty so that it will show all days
                eliminateDays = new int[] { };
            }
            // filter collection
            var dropDownItems = (from day in enumDaysCollection
                                 let days = eliminateDays
                                 where !days.Contains(day.Value)
                                 select new SelectListItem
                                 {
                                     Text = day.Text,
                                     Value = Convert.ToString(day.Value)
                                 }).ToList();
            //send dropdownlist values to view
            ViewBag.DropDownItems = dropDownItems;
```

And finally assign SelectListItem collection to dropdownlist

```
@Html.DropDownList("DaysName", (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.DropDownItems, "Select Days..", new { @class = "dropdown" })
```