# List to display enum values in a check-list-box

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, model-view-controller, enums

In a viewModel, I've created an enum for the different months of the year and also created properties of a class.

```
 public class Lists
{

    public enum Months
    {
        Jan = 0,
        Feb = 1,
        Mar = 2,
        Apr = 3,
        May = 4,
        Jun = 5,
        Jul = 6,
        Aug = 7,
        Sep = 8,
        Oct = 9,
        Nov = 10,
        Dec = 11
    }
 public object Month { get; set; }
 public bool isChecked { get; set; }
```

In the controller I've created an object list and tried adding the month names to that list by using the GetValues method.

```
public class SchedulerController : Controller
{
    // GET: Scheduler
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult schedulerIndex()
    {
        List<Lists> lst = new List<Lists>();
lst.Add(new Lists { Month = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Lists.Months)), isChecked = false });
```

I then created a view where I tried adding a checklist box. However, when I try running the webapp, all that is displayed in the checkbox is system.string[].

How do i get it to display names instead?

Comment: Your property needs to be `public Months Month { get; set; }` and you need to add one item to the collection for each value in your `enum`

Comment: You can check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43447985/how-to-filter-enum-and-use-it-in-dropdown/43448087#43448087

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved the problem. I created a foreach loop that added each value of the enum to the list.

```
        foreach (Lists.Months month in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Lists.Months)))
        {
            lst.Add(new Lists { Month = month, IsChecked = false });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
Enum.GetNames(typeof(Lists.Months)).OfType<string>()
  .ForEach(m => lst.Add(new Lists { Month = m, isChecked = false });
```